# VMware vCenter API with C# - InitiateFileTransferToGuest fails

Tags: c#, api, vmware

I'm trying to use the InitiateFileTransferToGuest method to send a file to a VM. Unfortunately, I'm getting stuck. Here's the related code where VClient is the VimClient with an already successfull connection:

```
GuestOperationsManager VMOpsManager = new GuestOperationsManager(VClient, VClient.ServiceContent.GuestOperationsManager);
GuestFileManager VMFileManager = new GuestFileManager(VClient, VClient.ServiceContent.FileManager);
GuestAuthManager VMAuthManager = new GuestAuthManager(VClient, VClient.ServiceContent.AuthorizationManager);

NamePasswordAuthentication Auth = new NamePasswordAuthentication()
{
    Username = "username",
    Password = "password",
    InteractiveSession = false
};

VMAuthManager.ValidateCredentialsInGuest(CurrentVM.MoRef, Auth);

System.IO.FileInfo FileToTransfer = new System.IO.FileInfo("C:\\userlist.txt");
GuestFileAttributes GFA = new GuestFileAttributes()
{
    AccessTime = FileToTransfer.LastAccessTimeUtc,
    ModificationTime = FileToTransfer.LastWriteTimeUtc
};

string TransferOutput = VMFileManager.InitiateFileTransferToGuest(CurrentVM.MoRef, Auth, "C:\\userlist.txt", GFA, FileToTransfer.Length, false);
```

First error shows up when getting to the ValidateCredentialsInGuest method. I get this message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'VMware.Vim.VimException' occurred in VMware.Vim.dll Additional information: The request refers to an unexpected or unknown type.

If I remove that validation, I get the same error when trying to run InitiateFileTransferToGuest. I've been browsing the API documentation, and threads in VMware forums and a lot of places to be honest. The only pieces of code I've seen posted where it works were in Java and Perl, but the API implementation is a little different than C#. Any idea where to look?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I made it work after testing and making up stuff. I ***guessed*** the MoRef for both AuthManager and FileManager doing the following:

```
ManagedObjectReference MoRefFileManager = new ManagedObjectReference("guestOperationsFileManager");
GuestFileManager VMFileManager = new GuestFileManager(VClient, MoRefFileManager);
ManagedObjectReference MoRefAuthManager = new ManagedObjectReference("guestOperationsAuthManager");
GuestAuthManager VMAuthManager = new GuestAuthManager(VClient, MoRefAuthManager);
```

Now it's working, and I have no idea how.

Comment: Thank you! Worked for me also. Much appreciate the prior research on this.